# Run triggered postgresql function on hsqldb

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, hsqldb

I can't find solution about transfering my function.

Lets manage working function and trigger on postgresql as below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func_check_minutes() RETURNS trigger AS
        $$
        BEGIN
        IF (SELECT minutes + NEW.minutes FROM employees WHERE date = NEW.date) > 50
        THEN RETURN NULL;
        END IF;

        RETURN NEW;

        END;
        $$
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

        CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_minutes
        BEFORE INSERT ON employees
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_check_minutes();
```

Is it even possible to run this function on hslqdb?

Because when I try to run it (obviously without language command) there is an error:

> DatabaseException: unexpected token: TRIGGER

I have syntax error, so I dont know if it's even possible. I was reading about functions and triggers in hsqldb from documentation, but did'nt notice any example about triggered functions in hsqldb.

With help from @fredt I created query:

```
<sql dbms="hsqldb">
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_check_minutes
    CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_minutes
    BEFORE INSERT ON hours_worked
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN ATOMIC
        IF (SELECT sum(minutes) + NEW.minutes FROM hours_worked WHERE date = NEW.date) > 1440
        THEN RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
    END
</sql>
```

But it prints an error:
 user lacks privilege or object not found: NEW.DATE

Comment: It is possible. You do not need a separate function for a simple trigger like this. The syntax is discussed here http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/triggers-chapt.html

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the INSERT to fail when too many hours are worked, you can throw an exception:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_minutes
BEFORE INSERT ON hours_worked
REFERENCING NEW ROW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC
    IF (SELECT sum(minutes) + NEW.minutes FROM hours_worked WHERE date = NEW.date) > 1440
    THEN 
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'too many hours';
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Your solution looks like it works, but there is an error: unexpected end of statement:  required: ; : line: 7
But I have there ; at that specific line (SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'too many hours';)

Comment: You are using a tool to execute the SQL and the tool is cutting the SQL when it reaches the first semicolon.

Comment: You're right, I just had to change end delimeter. Thanks for your time and much effort! :)